# FlannBasedMatcher has no member knnMatch

Tags: stl, image-stitching, flann

I am trying to use the Flann matcher for matching features between images. Following are few lines of code:

```
vector<MatchesInfo> matches;
Ptr<FlannBasedMatcher> matcher(new flann::LshIndexParams(20, 10, 2));  
matcher.knnMatch(afeatures.descriptors, bfeatures.descriptors, matches, 2);
```

This generates the following error:

> class "cv::Ptr" has no member "knnMatch"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vector<vector< DMatch >> knnMatches;
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
matcher.knnMatch(desc1, desc2, knnMatches, 50);
```

If using KNN would also used Lowe's ratios to determine if distance is appropriate between matches. Also make sure that descriptors are of type `CV_32F`

Comment: vector<vector<...> > is a matrix, I need the result to be a vector. Also there is no predefined method of converting a matrix of type DMatch to a vector of type MatchesInfo.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `cv::Ptr`, you need to use arrow pointer: `->`

But you used dot pointer: `.`

Change your code as:

```
matcher->knnMatch(afeatures.descriptors, bfeatures.descriptors, matches, 2);
```